# Changes made from the wagtail admin does not reflect on the front-end

Tags: django, wagtail

Changes made from the wagtail admin does not implement at the front end.

I have confirmed that changes made to the wagtail admin reflect on at the django admin layer. Still after multiple reloads, the changes made do not reflect on the front end.

models.py:

```
class AboutUs(models.Model):
    """
    This holds the info being displayed at the '/authors' page.
    This model just stores info about the blog, it's visions and what it hopes to achieve through the internet
    """
    id = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=True,
                                     unique=True,
                                     primary_key=True
                                     )
    title = models.CharField("Title of About Us Text",
                             max_length=100,
                             null=True,
                             blank=True,
                             help_text="Default can be named 'Default', Christmas season can be named 'Christmas'"
                             )
    about_us = RichTextField("About us",
                             null=True,
                             blank=True,
                             features=['bold', 'italic', 'hr', 'link', 'document-link', 'embed'],
                             )
    date_created = models.DateField()
    our_story = RichTextField("Our Story",
                              null=True,
                              blank=True,
                              features=['bold', 'italic', 'hr', 'link', 'document-link', 'embed'],
                              )
    our_vision = RichTextField("Our Vision",
                               null=True,
                               blank=True,
                               features=['bold', 'italic', 'hr', 'link', 'document-link', 'embed']
                               )
    our_quote = RichTextField("Our Quote",
                              null=True,
                              blank=True,
                              features=['bold', 'italic', 'hr', 'link', 'document-link', 'embed']
                              )
    author_of_quote = models.CharField("Quote Author", null=True,
                                       blank=True,
                                       max_length=100
                                       )

    panels = [
        FieldPanel('title'),
        FieldPanel('about_us'),
        FieldPanel('date_created'),
        FieldPanel('our_story'),
        FieldPanel('our_vision'),
        FieldPanel('our_quote'),
        FieldPanel('author_of_quote'),
    ]

    template = 'templates/about.html'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

about.html:

```
    {% include "nav_and_navbars/nav_and_navbars.html" %}
        <div class="page-header">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-offset-1 col-md-10 text-center">
                        {% if about_us %}
                        {% for inspiration in about_us %}
                        <h1> <!--class="text-uppercase"-->About <font style = "font-family:broadway regular">IXORABLOOM</font></h1>
                        <p class="lead">{{ inspiration.about_us|richtext }}</p>
                        {% endfor %}
                        {% endif %}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /PAGE HEADER -->
    </header>
    <!-- /HEADER -->

    <!-- SECTION -->
    <div class="section">
        <!-- container -->
        <div class="container">
            <!-- row -->
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-5">
                    <div class="section-row">
                        {% for story_base in about_us %}
                        {% if about_us %}
                        <div class="section-title">
                            <h2 class="title">Our story</h2>
                        </div>
                        <p>{{  story_base.our_story|richtext }}</p>
                        <blockquote class="blockquote">
                            <p>{{  story_base.our_quote|richtext }}</p>
                            <footer class="blockquote-footer">{{ story_base.author_of_quote }}</footer>
                        </blockquote>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-7">
                    <div class="section-row">
                        <div class="section-title">
                            <h2 class="title">Our Vision</h2>
                        </div>
                        <p>{{ story_base.our_vision|richtext }}</p>
                        {% endif %}
                        {% endfor %}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- /row -->
        </div>
        <!-- /container -->
    </div>
    <!-- /SECTION -->

    {% include "footer_and_js/footer_and_js.html" %}
```

I expect the text changes that I've made to the wagtail admin to be displayed on the front-end but still after several reloads, it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unlike [StateReloader](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/releases/2.2.1/) by Django that automatically restarts the server after a [significant] change in the code base has been detected, when there is a change at the wagtail admin layer, there is effectively no change to the code base but the database modified. Since there is no change at the code base level, there is no restart or reloading of the server.

The server would have to be manually restarted before changes can be implemented to the front end.

Comment: It is unclear what changes you are making. Django only restarts the sever when run in development mode (i.e. `./manage.py runserver`). Wagtail is built on Django so any Python code changes will trigger the reload. Changes to templates will not trigger this. If you make any changes to your content, then they should show up, unless you have a layer of caching, which again is unclear from your porst

Comment: Yes you are absolutely right. After closer observation, I found out that the contents of the page related to the change made from the wagtail admin (**RichTextField**) only updated after I manually stopped and restarted the development server. If Django doesn't have caching automatically enabled, then I don't think that there is any layer of caching at all. So for now, after any changes are made from the wagtail admin (i.e modifying the database), I would have to manually stop and restart the server then reload the page to see the changes take place on the front-end